# Feeding documents in Vespa

Tags: embedding, nearest-neighbor, vespa, vector-database

Struggling to feed in document in Vespa using json file. Getting 400 response.
[image: services.xml]

[image: neighbors.sd]

[image: feed.json]

[image: Error]

Comment: Please post codes/errors as [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents you try to feed have the field "point" while your schema defines the field "embedding".

And: The documents you try to feed specified the document type "point", while the schema defines the type "neighbours".

Answer (score 1):

Using `vespa feed --verbose`, you would see the feed response, the reason for the 400 bad requests. It would say that `point` is not a document type.